# Excel office script - Delete row (except first 2 columns) after row has been copied to a new tab

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I have a script that will move a row to another table if a certain cell within that row is filled.
The script then deletes the entire row. I would like for this to continue but instead of deleting the entire row it would be great if it deleted the entire row excepting the first 2 columns.

The current script is below:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    // You can change these names to match the data in your workbook.
    const TARGET_TABLE_NAME = 'TableNAdded';
    const SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = 'TableN';

    // Select what will be moved between tables.
    const FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX = 27;
    const FILTER_VALUE = 'Y';

    // Get the Table objects.
    let targetTable = workbook.getTable(TARGET_TABLE_NAME);
    let sourceTable = workbook.getTable(SOURCE_TABLE_NAME);

    // If either table is missing, report that information and stop the script.
    if (!targetTable || !sourceTable) {
        console.log(`Tables missing - Check to make sure both source (${TARGET_TABLE_NAME}) and target table (${SOURCE_TABLE_NAME}) are present before running the script. `);
        return;
    }

    // Save the filter criteria currently on the source table.
    const originalTableFilters = {};
    // For each table column, collect the filter criteria on that column.
    sourceTable.getColumns().forEach((column) => {
        let originalColumnFilter = column.getFilter().getCriteria();
        if (originalColumnFilter) {
            originalTableFilters[column.getName()] = originalColumnFilter;
        }
    });

    // Get all the data from the table.
    const sourceRange = sourceTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    const dataRows: (number | string | boolean)[][] = sourceTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();

    // Create variables to hold the rows to be moved and their addresses.
    let rowsToMoveValues: (number | string | boolean)[][] = [];
    let rowAddressToRemove: string[] = [];

    // Get the data values from the source table.
    for (let i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
        if (dataRows[i][FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX] === FILTER_VALUE) {
            rowsToMoveValues.push(dataRows[i]);

            // Get the intersection between table address and the entire row where we found the match. This provides the address of the range to remove.
            let address = sourceRange.getIntersection(sourceRange.getCell(i, 0).getEntireRow()).getAddress();
            rowAddressToRemove.push(address);
        }
    }

    // If there are no data rows to process, end the script.
    if (rowsToMoveValues.length < 1) {
        console.log('No rows selected from the source table match the filter criteria.');
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Adding ${rowsToMoveValues.length} rows to target table.`);

    // Insert rows at the end of target table.
    targetTable.addRows(-1, rowsToMoveValues)

    // Remove the rows from the source table.
    const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();

    // Remove all filters before removing rows.
    sourceTable.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();

    // Important: Remove the rows starting at the bottom of the table.
    // Otherwise, the lower rows change position before they are deleted.
    console.log(`Removing ${rowAddressToRemove.length} rows from the source table.`);
    rowAddressToRemove.reverse().forEach((address) => {
        sheet.getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
    });

    // Reapply the original filters. 
    Object.keys(originalTableFilters).forEach((columnName) => {
        sourceTable.getColumnByName(columnName).getFilter().apply(originalTableFilters[columnName]);
    });
}
```

I didn't even know where to start with this.

Comment: Can you console.log the values in `rowAddressToRemove`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Which values?

Comment: I just want to see the values in the `rowAddressToRemove` variable. So just run a statement like `console.log(rowAddressToRemove)`. Once you get the data in the console, add a comment with the data.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie at this really and have mainly copied this code from elsewhere, sorry. 
Is that something you do with VBA or online automate? I typed it in but it said the following in the "output" area: Line #37: ',' expected.
 let console.log(rowAddressToRemove): string[] = []

Line #37: ',' expected.
 let console.log(rowAddressToRemove): string[] = []

Line #37: ';' expected.
 let console.log(rowAddressToRemove): string[] = []

Line #37: An element access expression should take an argument.
 let console.log(rowAddressToRemove): string[] = []

Comment: Foud solution using ChatGBT edited section to below:
 // Get the data values from the source table.
  for (let i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    if (dataRows[i][FILTER_COLUMN_INDEX] === FILTER_VALUE) {
      rowsToMoveValues.push(dataRows[i]);

      // Get the intersection between table address and the entire row where we found the match. This provides the address of the range to remove.
      let address = sourceRange.getIntersection(sourceRange.getCell(i, 0).getEntireRow()).getAddress();
      rowAddressToRemove.push(address);
    }
  }